# UIView, CMDeviceMotionHandler : unowned may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

Tags: swift, closures

I'm creating a UIView that listens to `CMDeviceMotion` Events:

```
class MyView: UIView{


    private var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let motionQueue = NSOperationQueue()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){
        self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.5
        self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame(.XArbitraryZVertical, toQueue: self.motionQueue, withHandler: self.motionHandler)
    }

    // MARK: - CMDeviceMotionHandler

    let motionHandler : CMDeviceMotionHandler = {
        [unowned self] (motion,error) in
    }
}
```

I'd like to declare my `CMDeviceMotionHandler` closure as a member variable however I get the error:

> 'unowned' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types,
>   not 'MyView -> () -> MyView'

`MyView` is a `UIView` which in turn is a class so I don't get why it's complaining that `unowned` can not be applied.

I've searched for other questions with the same issue but most of them dealt with lazily computed variables. How do I resolve this error for my scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line of code you're on is actually run during the `init` function. `self` is not available until *after* all stored properties are initialized. You're in the middle of the process.

The error message is quite confusing and useless, because `self` in the context of property initializers is not an *instance* of a `MyView`, but a tricky meta-type: a class-member function that is unbound to its instance, but becomes bound and usable once the instance is passed in as the first argument. It's to do with member functions being implemented in Swift with *currying*, and is rather academic unless you love type calculus.

You have two options:

1. Declare it indeed as `lazy var` instead of `let`, so the code is *not* run during `init` but in fact at first use.
2. Declare it without initialization as an Optional. Depending on your design constraints this is either cumbersome or elegant. No way to know. Anyway, before it is needed, initialize it to a non-nil value. An easy place to do this, if this `UIView` is used strictly within Storyboard, is to initialize it within `awakeFromNib()`.

Comment: Thanks for such an informative answer. I went with the second approach and it worked fine :)